# Implicit Differentation of Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

"Let D be $R^2$ \  {$(x,0) | x \leq 0$}. The polar angle gives for each $(x,y)$ a value $\theta(x,y)$ in the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$. The function $\theta$ is continuous and differentiable on D.

a) Show that $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac {x}{x^2+y^2} $

b) Find the integral curves (filed lines) for the gradient vector field $\nabla \theta$

Okay, I'm pretty lost here.

a) I would assume that you're going to use implicit differention on $x=rcos\theta, y=rsin\theta, r^2=x^2+y^2$. Don't know where to take it from here though.

b) If I'm correct the integral curves are just $\nabla \theta = (\theta_x, \theta_y)$ so can't really do anything here without a.

Comment: Hint: what is $\tan \theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Correct! You can now partially differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ (remembering to use the chain rule for the LHS).

Comment: Sorry, accidently deleted my comment, so for the sake of others that may read this post I just copy in the same answer: $tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}$ so $\theta=arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. Still doesn't really help me though

Comment: $\newcommand{\p}{\partial}$Do you know how to find $\frac{\p}{\p y}(\tan \theta)$ using the chain rule (it's like implicit differentiation)?

Comment: Oh, so basically what I use is: $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}$ which means that the derivative with respect to y of $\theta = arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ is: $\theta_y = \frac{1}{(\frac{y}{x})^2 + 1} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: That is the correct answer for $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}$! If you are using $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, then there is no need for the chain rule, it's simple partial differentiation (just like how you would find $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}( x^2 y^3)$ or any function of $x$ and $y$: differentiate with respect to $y$, treating $x$ as constant). You can do this since you have expressed $\theta$ explicitly in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yeah, realised that just when I posted it. For the sake of learning, if I didn't remember the derivative of arctan then I would need to use implicit differentiation with respect y, right? How would I do that?

Comment: To do this, use the fact that $\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x}$, then just implicitly differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ (treat $x$ as a constant!). If you remember how to do implicit differentiation for something like $e^{z} = t^2 + t$ to find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ from single variable calculus, it's the exact same method.

Comment: Hmm, I've been trying that now but can't get remotely close. Would you mind giving some hint on how to start it? 

I basically got: $\frac{1}{cos^2(\theta)}\theta_y = \frac{1}{x}$ which doesn't seem correct at all

Comment: That is correct! If you rearrange that, you will yet $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac{\cos^2 \theta}{x}$. Now just remember that $\color{magenta}{\cos \theta = \frac{x}{r}}$ in polar coordinates (and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$) and clean up the algebra to finish off.

Comment: Ah, now i see. Thanks a lot!